# How to calculate streaks of consecutive dates for a user

Tags: mysql

Assume a results table like so:

date|user_id

A user can have one or more result per day..

I need to calculate a) users who have entered a result in 30 or more consecutive days b) preferably the longest current streak for a specific user.

The results table is large (2 million results) with approx 50k users.

Alternatively, if this is too difficult, any suggestions of a different way of working this out?

(e.g. create a 'streak' table with user_id, streak number, start date etc and then update that on insert into results, but you'd still need to know if somebody entered a result whether that was part of a streak etc)

Answer (score 2):

To keep track of longest streak and when it occurred.

Table columns needed:

```
current_streak          int
longest_streak          int
longest_streak_end_date datetime
```

Pseudocode:

```
if user has logged in today already
    return
if user logged in yesterday
    add 1 to current_streak
    if current_streak > longest_streak
        set longest_streak = current_streak
        set longest_streak_end_date = today
else
    set current_streak = 1
```

Comment: This would work assuming data is added in ascending date order. However, if a user adds three results, in the order of Jan 3, Jan 2, Jan 1, then the current streak value would only be "one". However, I think maintaining a separate table must be the way forward. What I need then maybe is a query that replaces "if user logged in yesterday" with "if date is part of a streak". e.g. when a user enters the results as above, it would see that the Jan 1 date was part of a continuous streak afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

To recompute the streaks for the entire table of 2M rows, you must find a way to do it in a single pass, O(N).  This probably involves walking through (ie, with `ORDER BY`) the table, setting/using @variables as you go.

By using `ORDER BY user, date`, you can collect the streaks for each user before moving on to the next user.

To capture just the streaks, not intermediate results, put that into a subquery and have a `WHERE` clause in the outer query to fetch only the endpoints.

Put the results into another table of (user + streak_length +  end_date) for further analysis (eg, look for longest) and reporting.

Examples of similar tasks are in [groupwise max](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max).